# Swift Realm - How to COUNT all data from single column?

Tags: ios, swift, database, count, realm

Here is what my class looks like:

```
class Card : Object {
    @objc dynamic var tags: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var set_id: String = ""
}
```

I want to return number of **tags** from all **Cards** with forwarded **set_id**. 
Here is the method:

```
func totalTags() -> String {
        var tagCounter: Int = 0
        let realm = try? Realm()
        let totalCards = realm!.objects(Card.self).filter("set_id = '\(setId)'") //all Cards with selected set_id, set_id is global var.
        for card in 0...totalCards.count {
            //every 'card' has tags, but there there can me more tags,
            //like : tags="one,twitter,world,Europe"...
            //And I want to count all of them for every 'card'
            let result = realm.objects(Card.self).filter() //How to filter?
            tagCounter += //what? result.count or something?
        }
        return String(tagCounter)
    }
```

Comment: your for loop does nothing since you do not use the 'card' instance. Shown the actual code you were implementing.

Comment: This is my actual code. i know something does nothing, so i posted a question here :) , can you help?

Comment: I am going outside the box here but why store a comma delimited string in tags? How about creating a TagClass realm object and a property within a Card called `let tagList = List<TagClass>`. Then you can a) reuse the tags  b) create links from tags back to Cards and c) the answer becomes simple; to get the tag count for each card just do `let totalTagsForThisCard = someCard.tagList.count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that `tags: String` contains comma separated elements and you want to find the number of elements.

You can do that by iterating over `totalCards`. For each `card`, split the `tags` into an array and count the number of elements.

```swift
for card in totalCards {
    tagCounter += card.tags.components(separatedBy: ",").count
}
```

`components(separatedBy:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410120-components)

Comment: Thank you man :) I just needed to add your code in *if card.tags != ""* because tags are by default *""* so it counts +1

Answer (score 0):

I know this was already answered but I just want to share how to do it my own way.

```
let tagsCount = totalCards.map { $0.tags.components(separatedBy: ",") }.flatMap { $0 }.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.reduce(into: 0, { result, _  in
        result += 1
 })
```

Thanks. Happy coding :)